# a limit of the digamma function

Tags: limits, special-functions

Numerical calculations show that:

$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\psi(x)+\psi(x/2)\right) = 0.$$

Can anybody help to find a formal proof of the above limit?

Answer (score 1):

For $\psi ^{(0)}(x)$, Taylor expansion around $x=0$ is given by $$-\frac{1}{x}-\gamma +\frac{\pi ^2 x}{6}+\frac{x^2 \psi ^{(2)}(1)}{2}+\frac{\pi ^4
   x^3}{90}+\frac{x^4 \psi ^{(4)}(1)}{24}+\frac{\pi ^6 x^5}{945}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ Apply it to the expression and the final result is $$-\frac{\pi ^2 x}{12}$$

Comment: Your expansion may be written using $\zeta$ as, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Taylor_series) :
$$\psi(1+x)=-\gamma-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \zeta(n+1)\;(-x)^n$$
Note that at the end we should take the limit as $x\to 0$ so that the final result should be $0$. Your result shows something stronger : $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac 1x-\psi(x)+\psi(x/2)}x=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$. Cheers,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni. Here comes the specialist ! I was wondering if I should meet you in this post. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

By exploiting:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+a)(n+b)}=\frac{\psi(a)-\psi(b)}{a-b} \tag{1}$$
we have that our limit equals:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{x}+\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{n+x}-\frac{1}{n+\frac{x}{2}}\right)\right)&=&\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n+x}-\frac{2}{2n+x}\right)\\&=&-\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\cdot\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(n+x)(2n+x)}\\&=&\color{red}{0}.\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
That also proves:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{\psi(x)-\psi(x/2)}{x}\right)=-\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}.\tag{3}$$